# Adjektive als Adverb nutzen

Tags: adjective, declension

Bitte schauen Sie sich folgende Sätze an:

> *Die Nachbarn hören oft laut Musik.*

> *Im Hotel gab es typisch deutsches Essen.*

Die Wörter "laut" und "typisch" sind nur Adjektive und es gibt Nomen nach ihnen. Meine Fragen sind:

1 - warum sind sie nicht "laute Musik" und "typisches deutsches Essen"?

2 - Sind deklinierte Wörter auch richtig?

3 - in welchen Situationen können wir undeklinierte Adjektive nutzen?

Comment: Vielen Dank Herr Halvarf fürs Korrigieren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Den ersten Satz sehe ich als eine umgangssprachliche Kontamination (Verschmelzung / Vermischung) von

- Die Nachbarn haben ihre Musik oft laut gestellt.
- etwas laut tun: laut sprechen, laut Saxophon spielen, die Tür laut zuknallen ...

Für mich wäre *... hören oft laute Musik* naheliegender; allerdings erscheint mir der Satz

> Die Nachbarn hören ihre Musik oft sehr laut

relativ umgangssprachlich-natürlich.

Das *typisch* im zweiten Beispiel ist ein adverbialer Gebrauch; *typisch* ist hier die Eigenschaft *deutsch* des Essens, und der Gesamtausdruck *typisch deutsch* bezieht sich auf das Essen. *Ein typisches deutsches Essen* kann umgangssprachlich vermutlich vorkommen, es passt aber logisch nicht, denn die Bedeutung ist nicht

- Das Essen ist *typisch*
- und das Essen ist *deutsch*,

sondern nur

- Das Essen ist *typisch deutsch*.

Adverbien haben im Deutschen weder Kasus- noch Genus- noch Numerusmarkierungen.

Undeklinierte Adjektive bzw. Adjektiv-Adverbien (= adverbial gebrauchte Adjektive) gibt es

- als **Subjekt-Prädikativ** nach *sein, bleiben, werden*: *Das Wetter ist schön / bleibt schön / wird schön*; auch bei *salzig schmecken, gut aussehen, sich weich anfühlen, sich gut anhören* usw.; die letzten Fälle werden von Grammatiken teilweise als Adverbien aufgefasst, weil sie mit *wie?* erfragt werden können;
- als **Objekt-Prädikativ** in vielen Ausdrücken wie *etwas interessant finden, jemanden für intelligent halten* ...
- im **adverbialen Gebrauch mit Verben**: *schnell fahren, kurz anhalten, etwas lang und breit erklären* ...
- **adverbial bei Adjektiven**: *ein unglaublich spannender Film, hell angestrichene Wände* ...
- **adverbial bei Adverbien**: *Er fuhr* wahnsinnig *schnell, die Sachen* schrecklich *umständlich in Kisten packen* ...
- als **freies Prädikativ (Depiktiv)**: *die Wäsche* ungebügelt *in den Schrank legen,* wütend *die Gruppe verlassen, seinen Kaffee* schwarz *trinken* ...
- in vielen **verbalen Ausdrücken**, die als Vokabeln gelernt werden müssen: *frei haben, zu kurz kommen* ...
- in sehr vielen **trennbaren Verben**: *sich hocharbeiten, den Kaffee warmstellen, falschspielen, dichthalten (der Polizei nichts erzählen), fremdgehen (den Partner betrügen), kleinschneiden* ...
- **super** bleibt immer undekliniert: *ein super Film, eine super Sache*; ähnlich verhalten sich *klasse* und *Hammer*, bei denen nicht klar ist, ob sie als Adjektive empfunden werden; diese sind alle umgangssprachlich;
- ein paar **nachgestellte Adjektive**, ungefähr mit der Bedeutung 'komplett, mehr als genug': *wir hatten im Urlaub Sonne* satt; *das war Natur* pur; *wir haben Zeit* satt; *am Wochenende ist hier Gedränge* total ...

Answer (score 4):

"Laut" wird hier als Adverb benutzt, nicht als Attribut. Das klingt zuerst etwas unlogisch, weil das Hören ja eigentlich nicht laut ist, sondern die Musik laut ist. Aber hier ist tatsächlich gemeint, dass die Nachbarn etwas *laut* tun , nämlich "Musik hören". Wenn die Nachbarn Musik hören, ist dieser Vorgang aus der Sicht von mir laut. Deshalb wird die Adverbform *laut* benutzt.

Man könnte auch sagen: *Die Nachbarn hören oft laute Musik.* Dann bezieht sich das "laute" direkt auf die Musik, nicht auf den Vorgang des Musikhörens.

Beim zweiten Satz bestimmt das Wort "typisch" das Attribut "deutsch" näher. Es ist also nicht "typisches Essen" gemeint, sondern das Essen ist "typisch deutsch". Wenn ein Adjektiv sich auf ein anderes Adjektiv bezieht, benutzt man die Adverbform des Adjektivs (*typisch*). "Typisches deutsches Essen" wäre hier etwas unsauber, denn es wird dann eigentlich nicht gesagt, wofür das Essen denn typisch ist. "Typisches" und "deutsches" beziehen sich dann beide direkt auf *Essen* und stehen nebeneinander, als hätten sie nichts miteinander zu tun.

> Er fährt ein gebraucht gekauftes Auto.
> (Das Auto war schon gebraucht, als er es gekauft hat.)

> Am Abend verlassen extrem müde Arbeiterinnen die Fabrik.
> (Die Arbeiterinnen sind nicht extrem, sondern extrem müde.)